# ORA-01722: invalid number при вставке в поле VARCHAR2

Tags: oracle

Есть пустая таблица с 2мя полями

```
IDRQ VARCHAR2(32 CHAR)
PROCID VARCHAR2(64 CHAR)
```

Пытаюсь вставить запись

```
INSERT INTO mySomeTable (IDRQ, PROCID)
VALUES('1', '3b721725-bdb6-4716-8b92-59a8cde+');
```

Получаю ошибку:

> ORA-01722: invalid number

Oracle 19

Что не так с данными?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка вызвана некорректным индексом по полю **PROCID**.

> Индекс построился для типа данных **Date** с конвертацией **varchar2** в тип **number**.

Индекс по полю построился вот такой:

```
TRUNC(TO_NUMBER(PROCID))
```

При выполнении команды

```
create index idx_PROCID on mySomeTable(trunc(PROCID));
```

Что для меня очень удивительно. Да есть ошибка в скрипте создания индекса, однако мне очень не понятно, почему *Oracle* вместо ошибки создания индекса, переделал тип данных? :( 
3 часа мучений, 200к ошибок вставки записей, а все из-за этого...

> Вопрос на тему: [Почему при создании индекса по функции trunc() на поле с типом varchar2, Oracle меняет функцию на trunc(to_number()), а не выдает ошибку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1467534/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-oracle-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-ora-01722)