# Почему Oracle меняет функцию построения индекса вместо вывода ошибки? ORA-01722: invalid number по индексу на поле с типом varchar2

Tags: oracle

Есть пустая таблица mySomeTable с 2мя полями

```
create table mySomeTable (
    IDRQ VARCHAR2(32 CHAR),
    PROCID VARCHAR2(64 CHAR)
);
```

Создаю индекс на таблице по полю **PROCID VARCHAR2(64 CHAR)** используя следующую команду:

```
create index idx_PROCID on mySomeTable(trunc(PROCID));
```

Как можно увидеть, в скрипте построения индекса допущена ошибка и скрипт будет пытаться построить индекс по функции trunc().

> **trunct()** - функция для работы с датами или числами

Данный скрипт построения индекса успешно отрабатывает и создает индекс, не выводя каких либо предупреждений и ошибок.

#### Создается индекс на таблице по функции TRUNC(*TO_NUMBER(PROCID)*)

При последующей попытке вставить или изменить запись в таблице, если, PROCID нельзя преобразовать в число, получаю ошибку **ORA-01722: invalid number**, что собственно логично.

Однако понимание того, что я работаю в таблице со строками и добавляю строковые значения в таблицу, а ошибка именно про преобразование к числу, вводило в заблуждение и не понимание происходящего...

Вопрос: **Почему Oracle меняет функцию построения индекса, вместо того, что бы выдать ошибку?** И как этого можно избежать в будущем?

Версия Oracle 19.14

> Пост с ошибкой [ORA-01722: invalid number при вставке в поле VARCHAR2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1467434/ora-01722-invalid-number-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5-varchar2) был сделан когда мистика не разгадывалась, но после опубликования вопроса, случайно увидел построенный индекс, т.к. начал перебирать все возможные и не возможные варианты.
>
> > Вот что [stackoverflow на русском делает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) - стоит задать вопрос и тут же находится решение.

Comment: *Есть пустая таблица mySomeTable с 2мя полями* Пожалуйста, полный CREATE TABLE, а не ошмётки от него. *Создается индекс на таблице по функции TRUNC(TO_NUMBER(PROCID))* Как именно это установлено?

Comment: create table поправил. Установлено это так - запускаем скрипт создания индекса из вопроса и в таблице видим получившийся индекс.

Comment: @Akina Создание индекса тестировал на 2-х экземплярах БД. Поведение одинаковое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ошибка** кроется в преобразовании типов! А Oracle их делает много.

> Функция **TRUNC** принимает в качестве параметра тип **NUMBER** или **DATE**.

Нам никто не запрещал хранить **числа** или **даты** в полях формата **VARCHAR2**.

В [документации oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-6DB331B5-0F34-4215-9A20-16AEA9D7FF4B) сказано:

- Если неявное преобразование типа данных происходит в выражении индекса, то база данных Oracle может не использовать индекс, поскольку он определен для типа данных, предшествующего преобразованию. Это может негативно сказаться на производительности.

**Oracle** рекомендует указывать явные преобразования, а не полагаться на неявные или автоматические преобразования.

Предположительно, именно поэтому Oracle на самом деле выбирает применение явного преобразования при создании индекса.

В любом случае, при выполнении запроса, получили бы ту же ошибку, если бы выражение индекса не было изменено. Неявное преобразование строки в число выдало бы ошибку **ORA-01722: invalid number**